# Structuring looker Explore Results

Tags: sql, visualization, looker

I’m having trouble figuring out how to count publications in my Looker data set by year and author. In my Looker explore the data Looker table results look like this:

| Pub_id | year | author | author_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1_1 | 2021 | john | 5.5 |
| 1_2 | 2020 | john | 5.5 |
| 1_3 | 2021 | jane | 2.0 |
| 1_4 | 2021 | jane | 2.0 |
| 1_5 | 2019 | garth | 3.6 |
| 1_6 | 2013 | wayne | 1.7 |

I want to create a bar chart that gives me the total number of publications per year, so:

x

x

x             x          x            x

2013    2019    2020     2021

My struggle is getting the count or aggregate of the count correct.

I’m also trying to crate an aggregate count by authors, so output would look like:

| Author | Number of publications |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2 |
| Jane | 2 |
| Wayne | 1 |
| Garth | 1 |

Thanks for help or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these aggregations should use a single `dimension` and a single `measure`. For both, the `measure` should be a simple [`count`](https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/reference/param-measure-types#count):

```
view: my_view {
  measure: number_of_publications {
    type: count
  }
}
```

Then in the explore, you should only select this measure and a single dimension (`year` for the first one and `Author` for the second), and you'll end up with a table like the one you posted above for `Author`.

Once you have the table, just select the bar chart type and you should be good to go.